# ggplot2: horizontal position of stat_summary with geom_boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I want to annotate mean of each boxplot using `ggplot2`. However, I could not figure out how to horizontally center the symbols marking the means within their respective boxes (see image below).

MWE is below for reference:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=mpg, mapping=aes(x=class, y=hwy)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(color = drv), outlier.shape = NA) +
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "point", size=2, aes(shape = drv, color = drv)) + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: I think the plotted points are in the right place; it's just that the lines in the boxplots are marking medians, not means. If you replace `mean` with `median` in the call to `stat_summary()`, you'll see what I mean (ha, ha).

Comment: @ulfelder: Thanks for your comment. Yes, you right `mean` and `median` are two different things and they could be different for the same data set. However, the point here is the horizontal positions of `means`.

Comment: Oh, you mean their position on the x-axis, not the y-axis? Probably good to specify what you mean by "properly position" in the question. You want them centered in the boxes?

Comment: Yes, @ulfelder you absolutely right. I want to put these means in the center of their respective boxes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try with `position_dodge()`

```
ggplot(data=mpg, mapping=aes(x=class, y=hwy)) + 
       geom_boxplot(aes(color = drv), outlier.shape = NA) +
       stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "point", size=2, aes(shape = drv, color = drv), 
                    position = position_dodge(width = .75)) + 
       theme_bw()
```